# Compare two char variable using strcmp in c++ shows invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, strcmp

This my code.

```
if(strcmp(s[0][i],s[rock][j])==0)
{           
     count[i]+=1;
     rock++;
}
```

Comment: Where's `s` defined?

Comment: What is the type of s?

Comment: strcmp is for string comparison... Use == for chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strcmp` function compares two *strings*. If you want to compare two `char` variables, just use `==` or `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that objects `s[0][i]` and `s[rock][j]` have type `char`. That is they are not strings but two characters. You can compare them using operator `==`

For example

```
if ( s[0][i] == s[rock][j] )
```

Also I would advice to substitute these two expression statements

```
 count[i]+=1;
 rock++;
```

for

```
 count[i]++;
 rock++;
```

or

```
 ++count[i];
 ++rock;
```

In this case the code looks more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume for this answer that s was declared as:

```
char s[100][100]; // or any arbitrary numeric limits
```

In this case, you cannot compare s[0][i] and s[rock][j] using strcmp, because they are characters, not character pointers.

Instead, you can just write:

```
if(s[0][i] == s[rock][j])
```

Answer (score 1):

`char` is primitive datatype - you can compare `char`s directly:

```
...
if (s[0][i] == s[rock][j])
{
...
```

`strcmp` function expects **strings**, i.e. `char *`, hence the error message. You could compare whole strings in `s` variable:

```
...
if (strcmp(s[0], s[rock]) == 0)
{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing to `char` don't use string compare function! The prototype of `strcmp` function is-

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2); // where s1 and s2 are strings
```

So for comparing to characters just use `==` or `!=`

```
if(s[0][i]==s[rock][j])
{
 count[i]++;
 rock++;
}
```